# How do you make the Red[X] on a JFrame have n second wait before exiting a program in Java?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe, windowlistener

I am using the `WindowListener` to this but the window closes immediately anyway.

Code:

```
WindowAdapter close =  new WindowAdapter()
{
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
  {
            try
            {
              Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ie3)
            {
              System.out.println("Sleep interrupted");
            }
            System.exit(0);      
  }
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you `setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)`
2. Use a `javax.swing.Timer` instead of trying and sleep the thread.

Here's an example. I set the `DELAY` to 3 seconds, but you can change it

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WindowClosing {
    private static final int DELAY = 3000;

    public WindowClosing() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
                ;
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        JFrame frame = createFrame(timer);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private JFrame createFrame(final Timer timer) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                timer.start();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "WindowClosing");
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        return frame;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new WindowClosing();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I found this much more effective than using a thread. Thanks.